# To add class="current" Dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

I have Menu list which contains Sub-Menu as shown in the code below.

```html
<li class="current">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="icon4"></span>Subscriptions</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href=" @Url.Content(" ~/SuperAdmin/ViewSubscriptions ") ">View Subscriptions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="@((ViewBag.PageName == " Subscription ") ? "active " : " ")"><a href="@Url.Content(" ~/SuperAdmin/ManageSubscriptionPlan ")">Manage Subscription Plans</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="current">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="icon5"></span>Administration</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="@((ViewBag.PageName == " AssetPage ") ? "active " : " ")"><a href="@Url.Content(" ~/SuperAdmin/AssetsPage ")">Assets</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Content(" ~/SuperAdmin/ConfigureText ")">Configure Text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=" @Url.Content(" ~/SuperAdmin/ErrorLog ")">Error Log</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=" @Url.Content(" ~/SuperAdmin/ProductSettings ") ">Product Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="current">
  <a href="#"><span class="icon6"></span>Promo Codes</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="@Url.Content(" ~/SuperAdmin/ManagePromoCode ")">Manage Promo Code</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=" @Url.Content(" ~/SuperAdmin/UserPromoCodeDetails ") ">Used Promo Code</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Here `Subscription`,`Administration`,`Promo Codes` are Menu Lists which contains Sub-Menu Lists under them.

The thing is I want to apply `class=current` dynamically when a user clicks on `Subscription`,Administration`,`Promo Codes`.

And I am doing this in `LayoutPage` of MVC.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which MVC are you using ??

Comment: I mean which framework  are you using ??

Comment: @SunilGehlot .net 4.5

Comment: One option would be to give your `<li>` elements an `id` attribute. Then pass the a `ViewBag.SelectedMenu = "xxx";` in the GET methods where `xxx` is the `id` to select, and then use javascript to add the class name.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Menu tag are only the static content means there will not be any navigation but sub-menu list will be shown.

Comment: But surely you want `class="current"` to be applied to the 2nd `<li>` element when you navigate to `/SuperAdmin/ConfigureText` or `SuperAdmin/ErrorLog` and not to the other `<li>` elements? (otherwise what is the point)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am applying `class="active"` on sub menu list and `class="current"` only to Menu. Hope you understand.
@JitendraTiwari when i click on Menu item it will not refresh but give you the Sub-Menu list and click on Sub-Menu item will refresh page.

Comment: Then all you need is `$(.mainmenu').click(function() { $(this).prev('li').addClass('current'); });` and give those 3 links a `class="mainmenu"` - although they already have that class name so not really sure what your trying to do here

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please put your last comment in separate post except last 6-7 words :P

Comment: But I aren't sure what you want to do :) Do you intend to remove `class="current"` from the view you have shown so that its only added on the click event? What about when you click another link - do you want the class removed from the previous one. And if you were to navigate to `SuperAdmin/ManagePromoCode`, should the 3rd `<li>` be initially renedered with that class name?

Comment: @StephenMuecke `class="current"` would apply only to `Subscription`,`Administration`,`Promo Codes` whenever any one of that options will b clicked. yes if i navigate to `ManagePrmoCode` then `class="current"` should be apply to `Promo Codes` only.

Comment: OK, give me an hour or so an I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the class name to the parent `<li>` element, give the main links a class name. Assuming you also want to remove it from any `<li>` elements that already have it, also give them a class name

```
<li class="container">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"class="mainmenu"><span class="icon4"></span>Subscriptions</a>
```

and the script will be

```
$('.mainmenu').click(function() {
    $('.container').removeClass('current'); // remove any previous
    $(this).closest('.container').addClass('current');
});
```

In addition, if when you navigate to one of the views with this layout, and what to add the class name to the appropriate element, then you can give the `<li>` elements an `id` attribute

```
<li id="subscriptions" class="container">
   ....
</li>
<li id="administration" class="container">
   ....
```

and in the GET method, pass the value of the `id` to the view (e.g. using `ViewBag`

```
public ActionResult ConfigureText()
{
    ViewBag.Menu = "administration";
    ....
    return View(...);
}
```

and add a script that runs when the page first loads

```
var menu = '@ViewBag.Menu";
$('#' + menu).addClass('current');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/c4h3sup9/

You have to use a little bit of Javascript for that.
You have to give the listitems a other class name like in my example "operator"

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.className == "operator"){         
    var actives = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    actives[0].setAttribute("class", "operator");
    e.target.setAttribute("class", "active");
  }
});
```

for this example you need to assing one element as active from the beginning.

**Note:**

LI elements are never parents of UL.

**The order is:**

Unordered List (Plural) -> List item (Singular, Child).

You might want to correct that as it is not standard conform.

Comment: OP wants to set the class when the user navigates to the page (setting immediately before the redirect is pointless) - and your fiddle does not and cannot work - it contains c# code